# Separation boundary was not specified (REST Easy Multipart File Upload)

Tags: java, http, resteasy, multipartform-data

I am trying to upload a file using REST easy

But I am getting error "Separation boundary was not specified"

In exception trace its trying to use below MultipartParses and it expects me to mention the Boundary... How exactly i decide what is the boundary?

http://www.javadocexamples.com/java_source/com/oreilly/servlet/multipart/MultipartParser.java.html

Comment: You might want to look at the [RESTeasy support for multipart](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.12.Final/userguide/html/Multipart.html). There is both server and client side support. You will need the multipart provider dependency [mentioned here](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.12.Final/userguide/html/Maven_and_RESTEasy.html)